# android scroller scroll from current position

Tags: android, scroller

I have TextView with auto-scrolling, which is looping forever. Plus user can scroll TextView himself. So when user has finished scrolling i want to auto-scroller continue scroll from position user has finished scrolling.

All problem is getting correct variable `mXPaused` value.

In very beginning `mXpaused = -1*getWidth();` So it starts scroll from left side.

After user has finished scrolling i try to assign new value

```
case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
        mXPaused = mSlr.getCurrX();
        resumeScroll();
        break;
```

But that value is always equal to `-540` (my screen width)

```
public void resumeScroll() {

mSlr.startScroll(mXPaused, 0, distance, 0, duration);

}
```

User scrolling:

```
@Override
    public boolean onScroll(MotionEvent e1, MotionEvent e2,
            float distanceX, float distanceY) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        scrollBy((int)distanceX, 0);
        return true;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

`mXPaused` should be 0 if you are starting from the far left, not `mXpaused = -1*getWidth()`.

try using `getScrollX()` instead of `getCurrX()`, I had similar problems trying to get the scroll position.